# Issue after disable MSI 2.4

Tags: magento2

I have issue with website after disable MSI:

```
Warning: include(/home/shop/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/ResourceModel/Stock/Status/Interceptor.php): failed to open stream
```

Anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` command.